# Hadoop job stucked at map 100% reduce 0%

Tags: java, hadoop, nutch

I am using hadoop 2.7.2 and nutch 1.12 together.When I run the nutch job in hadoop, I get following errors in nutch parsing stage.

```
17/10/03 14:01:52 INFO mapreduce.Job: Running job: job_1506573729189_0223
17/10/03 14:02:05 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1506573729189_0223 running in uber mode : false
17/10/03 14:02:05 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 0% reduce 0%
17/10/03 14:02:15 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 1% reduce 0%
17/10/03 14:02:18 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 2% reduce 0%
17/10/03 14:02:21 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 3% reduce 0%
17/10/03 14:02:24 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 4% reduce 0%
17/10/03 14:02:27 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 8% reduce 0%
17/10/03 14:02:30 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 12% reduce 0%
17/10/03 14:03:35 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1506573729189_0223_m_000000_0, Status : FAILED
Error: Java heap space
17/10/03 14:03:36 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 11% reduce 0%
17/10/03 14:03:46 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 14% reduce 0%
17/10/03 14:04:48 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1506573729189_0223_m_000000_1, Status : FAILED
Error: Java heap space
```

To remove the above error, I added the below change to hadoops mapred-site.xml.

```
<property>
    <name>mapred.child.java.opts</name>
    <value>-Xmx4096m</value>
  </property>
```

when I added this property ,I get new error as follows.

```
17/10/04 11:06:15 INFO mapreduce.Job: Running job: job_1507094901386_0004
17/10/04 11:06:26 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1507094901386_0004 running in uber mode : false
17/10/04 11:06:26 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 0% reduce 0%
17/10/04 11:06:28 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1507094901386_0004_m_000000_0, Status : FAILED
Container [pid=8299,containerID=container_1507094901386_0004_01_000002] is running beyond virtual memory limits. Current usage: 97.6 MB of 1 GB physical memory used; 5.7 GB of 2.1 GB virtual memory used. Killing container.
Dump of the process-tree for container_1507094901386_0004_01_000002 :
    |- PID PPID PGRPID SESSID CMD_NAME USER_MODE_TIME(MILLIS) SYSTEM_TIME(MILLIS) VMEM_USAGE(BYTES) RSSMEM_USAGE(PAGES) FULL_CMD_LINE
    |- 8299 8297 8299 8299 (bash) 0 0 17092608 707 /bin/bash -c /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/java -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dhadoop.metrics.log.level=WARN  -Xmx4096m -Djava.io.tmpdir=/tmp/hadoop-hduser/nm-local-dir/usercache/hduser/appcache/application_1507094901386_0004/container_1507094901386_0004_01_000002/tmp -Dlog4j.configuration=container-log4j.properties -Dyarn.app.container.log.dir=/usr/local/hadoop/logs/userlogs/application_1507094901386_0004/container_1507094901386_0004_01_000002 -Dyarn.app.container.log.filesize=0 -Dhadoop.root.logger=INFO,CLA -Dhadoop.root.logfile=syslog org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild 192.168.1.63 33402 attempt_1507094901386_0004_m_000000_0 2 1>/usr/local/hadoop/logs/userlogs/application_1507094901386_0004/container_1507094901386_0004_01_000002/stdout 2>/usr/local/hadoop/logs/userlogs/application_1507094901386_0004/container_1507094901386_0004_01_000002/stderr  
    |- 8303 8299 8299 8299 (java) 73 4 6100692992 24291 /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/java -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dhadoop.metrics.log.level=WARN -Xmx4096m -Djava.io.tmpdir=/tmp/hadoop-hduser/nm-local-dir/usercache/hduser/appcache/application_1507094901386_0004/container_1507094901386_0004_01_000002/tmp -Dlog4j.configuration=container-log4j.properties -Dyarn.app.container.log.dir=/usr/local/hadoop/logs/userlogs/application_1507094901386_0004/container_1507094901386_0004_01_000002 -Dyarn.app.container.log.filesize=0 -Dhadoop.root.logger=INFO,CLA -Dhadoop.root.logfile=syslog org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild 192.168.1.63 33402 attempt_1507094901386_0004_m_000000_0 2
```

These errors where removed by setting the properties as follows in
 mapred-site.xml.Also i remove the above property 'mapred.child.java.opts'

```
<property>
    <name>mapreduce.map.memory.mb</name>
    <value>4096</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>mapreduce.reduce.memory.mb</name>
    <value>8192</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>mapreduce.map.java.opts</name>
    <value>-Xmx3072m</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>mapreduce.reduce.java.opts</name>
    <value>-Xmx6144m</value>
  </property>
```

But even I stuck at the following line.

```
17/10/11 17:00:32 INFO mapreduce.Job: Running job: job_1507721357521_0001
17/10/11 17:00:56 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1507721357521_0001 running in uber mode : false
17/10/11 17:00:56 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 0% reduce 0%
17/10/11 17:01:08 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 0%
```

Comment: Have you taken a heap dump at the time of the issue?  What does it tell you?

Comment: Just an assumption: one large document (maybe ill-formed) which causes the parser to hang and consume a lot of memory. What are the values of the properties `http.content.limit`, `parser.skip.truncated` and `parser.timeout`? Also have a look into the task log file of the hanging task (ev. set `log4j.logger.org.apache.nutch.parse.ParserDebug=DEBUG`). If you can login to the machine running the task, try to get a stacktrace, e.g., via `sudo -u yarn jstack <pid>`.